# custom axis scale in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, scaling

Is there a simple way to obtain customized scaling on the plot axis?

e.g., the semilogy function provides {x, log10(y)} scaling such that one can automatically zoom in/ot and ticks and labels automatically adjust. I would like to have the same thing with the {x, asinh(2*y)} scaling. the solution:

```
plot (x, asinh (2*y));
set (gca, 'YTickLabel', num2str (sinh (get (gca, 'YTick')(:)) / 2, '%g'))
```

works for a "static" plot but I would like to have the ticks - label to autoadjust when zooming...

Comment: I believe you would have to scale it yourself and apply your custom tick marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the function of interest. It will scale the Y-Axis each time you zoom in/out. 'sinh' transform is used, but it could be any transform.

The matlab core function behind it is 'ActionPostCallback'. See http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html for details. The analogue function 'ActionPreCallback' could be used too. These little handy functions can also be used for the main functions 'rotate3d', 'pan', 'zoom' and 'brush'.

```
function applyCustomScalingWhenZooming  

%some data  
x=1:1/1000:100;  
y=1:1/1000:100;  

%figure  
figure;  
plot (x, asinh (2*y));  
set (gca, 'YTickLabel', ...  
    num2str ((sinh (get (gca, 'YTick')) / 2)(:), '%g')); %initial format  

%defines callback when zoom action  
h = zoom; %define handle for 'zoom'  
%action to be called right after zooming  
set(h,'ActionPostCallback', {@mypostcallback}); 


    function mypostcallback(obj,event_obj)    
    %format function     
    set (gca, 'YTickLabel', ...    
        num2str ((sinh (get (gca, 'YTick')) / 2)(:), '%g'));
```

Comment: sounds very nice. i'll check it out asap. as for the code, I forgot the transpose (typed the lines on the fly =) ) but the `sinh` is actually correct (the original-scale value is obtained trough the inverse of the scaling function)

Comment: Great - I removed the comments and changed the asinh/sinh back to its original state.