# 1/x scaled x axis in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

What is the matlab way to create transformed scaling on the x axis?

I use this workaround to plot an `1/x` scaled axis.

The problem here is, that plot does not plot data, but `1 ./` data in fact. So that one has to adjust fits, and all graphic elements in the plot later.

```
data = linspace(3,10,8);
plot(1./data, data) 

myxticksrange = linspace(10, 3, 8);

myxticks = 1 ./ myxticksrange;
myxtickslabels = arrayfun(@num2str, myxticksrange, 'UniformOutput', false);

set(gca,'XTick', myxticks)
set(gca,'XTickLabel', myxtickslabels)
```

[image: one over x Plot]

How can I improve this code? (The question was posted on Codereview.sx originally)

Comment: Did you try a semi-logarithmic scale?  What about `semilogx`?

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in function that does this or is there something specific that is wrong with your code? There's no way to get a 1/x scaling without calculating 1/x one way or another.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have Matlab do the 1/x scaling automatically. That can't be done. The only options for (automatic) axis scaling are `linear` or `log` (try `set(gca,'XScale')`)

Comment: @rayryeng my plot needs 1/x which is different from log(x)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Sure it can be done. You just have to write your own plotting / auto-scaling function. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17676225/2278029), for example. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @horchler I didn't know it could be done this way. So it is possible to tell Matlab to do that automatically, by defining your custom scaling functions and setting them as callbacks